# Firebase HomeActivity not redirecting to LoginActivity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use an AuthStateListener on my HomeActivity (the homepage / main page) in order to see whether the user is logged in, and if they're not, it redirects them to the LoginActivity page, I'm using the exact same setup on the LoginActivity page which redirects the user to the HomeActivity page if the user is logged in, but doesn't do it the other way around, i.e. the HomeActivity does not redirect to the LoginActivity. I've made the HomeActivity my LAUNCHER and MAIN in my AndroidManifest.

**HomeActivity declaration:**

```
FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
```

**HomeActivity in my onCreate() method:**

```
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if(mFirebaseUser != null) {
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Currently logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Intent i = new Intent (HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    };
```

**LoginActivity declaration**

```
FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
```

**LoginActivity onCreate() method code**

```
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if(mFirebaseUser != null) {
                Intent i = new Intent (LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
            else {

            }
        }
    };
```

It should also be noted that my *private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;* has a warning that says "Field can be converted to a local variable", even though I don't get this warning on the LoginActivity.

Comment: Add some logging statements at each possible code path.  What do those tell you?

Comment: Stack Overflow is an incredibly inefficient interactive debugger, so it's best to run the code in a debugger yourself. If you put a breakpoint on `if(mFirebaseUser != null) {` and run the app in a debugger, what is the value of `mFirebaseUser`?

Comment: Right, I've added a breakpoint there and ran it in debugger, how do I find the value from there? Sorry I'm not that good with the debugger at the moment

Comment: The execution of that code did not stop the program from running, it's still running, and didn't go through the breakpoint @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: i hope u have added authlistener to firebase auth, mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener)

Comment: Oh dear, I didn't have    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }

at the bottom of the code for HomeActivity, just added it now and it works!